# change event on drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to code a page to modify database entries.  I want to pull the database up and place the 3rd column into a drop down list.  When an item from the drop down list is selected I then want to have the info from the row that selection was in, in the database, to populate the form.  I have the drop down populated and working but my question would be, what am I doing wrong, or what would your suggestion be to code the change event?  I am attempting to use a jQuery change event but I am still learning and apparently I dont have it coded right.  I tried to start simple and just have it echo the item that was selected to make sure I have the on change correct first, but apparently I do not.

```
<?php
    include("header.html");
    include("connection.php");
    $query= "SELECT * FROM components";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $item="<p><select name='part' id='inp'>";
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $item.="<option>".$row[2]."</option>";
        }
        $item.="</select></p>";
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            $('select').on('change',function () {
                $sel=$(this).value;
            });
        </script>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="test"></div>
            <?php 
            echo $item;
            echo $sel;
            ?>
                <form method = "post">
                    <p><input name="itemnumber" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Item #"></p>
                    <p><input name="cost" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Price"></p>
                    <p><input name="company" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Company"></p>
                    <p><input name="contact" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Contact"></p>
                    <p><input name="address1" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Address"></p>
                    <p><input name="address2" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="City / State / Zip"></p>
                    <p><input name="phone" id ="inp" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number"></p>
                    <p><select name="part" id="inp">
                        <option value="select" selected>Choose One</option>
                        <option value="base">Base Product</option>
                        <option value="coating">Coating</option>
                        <option value="topping">Topping</option>
                        <option value="film">Film</option>
                        <option value="corrugate">Corrugate</option>
                    </select></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" value = "Submit"></p>
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php include("footer.html"); ?>
```

Comment: PHP executes on the server, you can't echo a javascript variable on the server, at that time the page has left the server and lives in the browser

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Sounds like you need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: `$(this).val()` not `$(this).value`

Comment: @j08691 thank you, I changed Id to class, I was using it for CSS purposes for the input boxes

Comment: @PatrickQ I will play around with ajax now and see what I can get.  I just watched a few videos about ajax and json yesterday although I think an ajax post to a php page to reach back out to the server would be what I wanted?

Comment: try to change this $item.="<option>".$row[2]."</option>";  to $item  .=" <option>".$row[2]."</option>"; as everything is connected, even         $item.="</select></p>"; to         $item  .="</select></p>";

Comment: allow space like this $variable .=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing is that you cannot execute php after the page is really loaded in the browser. 
So if you want to do any thing after the page is loaded, either you have to use javascript that executes in the browser or use javascript to do a request back to your server and execute php script.

Here your requirement is simple you need to show the selected value of dropdown in the page

```
<script>
$('select').on('change',function () {
    $('#selectedvalue').html($(this).val());
});
</script>


<?php
echo $item;
?>
<div id="selectedvalue"></div>
```

**Note:** I expect you include jquery library js in the page

Comment: This solution works great when I enter it in to JSfiddle, so I know your code is correct, for some reason it isnt working on my actual page though :-(  This tells me there is a seperate error that I cannot seem to find :-(  I am using the code from above, with your suggested corrections made.  I do include jQuery library, its inside of the header.html file.  I viewed source on my page to make sure it is being added and it is.

Comment: any idea why this may be?  I have been staring at my code and still cant find my mistake.  I dumped the code into JSbin so you can see the totally updated code.  Ignore the output window because it obviously wouldn't work properly.  http://jsbin.com/vujecewude/edit?html

Comment: Open page in chrome, press F12 to open developer tools and check console for any javascript error